# Perl, Can't read PDF cross-reference section, according to trailer

Tags: perl, pdf, corruption

I'm trying to read the contents of a pdf file. Here's the code

```
 4 use warnings;
 5 use strict;
 6
 7 use PDF;
 8
 9 print "*" x 30, "\n";
10 my $filename = shift;
11 print "Filename: $filename\n";
12
13 my $pdf = PDF->new($filename);
```

This is the output:

```
******************************
Filename: Calabasas, LA County June 2012 monthly-new-projects-report.pdf
Can't read cross-reference section, according to trailer
```

As I surf google I see this is somehow related to file corruption. But still I am able to open it with a pdf reader.

Should I try different Perl modules or is my code broken ?

Comment: I think PDF is outdated. I used CAM::PDF and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is what you are looking for (a pure perl solution or a windows one) but in Unix I call "pdftotext" to do the conversion for me and then I read the file:

```
open IN, '-|', '/usr/bin/pdftotext', $file, '-' 
    or die "couldn't open $file $!\n";
```

Hope it helps!